# How to make a firebase query for single document more efficient in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data of a user to be added to the state based off of a single query search from the user id of the user. I tried to do the single document path, which did not work for me as the firebase.auth().currentUser.uid is different from the doc.id, and the code that I use now is:

```
      firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);
            console.log(doc.data().email;
            if (doc.data().email) == firebase.auth().currentUser.email) {
              this.setState({
                avatar: doc.data().avatar,
                name: doc.data().name,
                email: doc.data().email
              });
            }
          });
        });
```

While this code works, it is incredibly inefficient as it goes through all the users and compares their email it the current user email. I would like to know if there was a way one could just search for the data without using this method. Any help would be largely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is solved by very standard querying.  I suggest reading the documentation to learn about how Firestore queries work.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this and comment if it worked out for you:

```
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .where('email', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) =>
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
          this.setState({
            avatar: doc.data().avatar,
            name: doc.data().name,
            email: doc.data().email
          })
      )
    );
```

Comment: Yes, this worked like a charm in both efficiency and logic! I appreciate your help!

Comment: I appreciate your consideration, If you need some extra help check my profile and contact me on discord, see you (: